# How to prevent PreviewKeyDown be called in parent class

Tags: c#

I have two controls.

```
class ControlA
{
    public ControlA()
    {
        //some code
        this.PreviewKeyDown += ControlA_PreviewKeyDown;
    }
    protected void ControlA_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // do A things
    }
}
```

I also have a control B which inherits control A

```
class ControlB : ControlA
{
    public ControlB()
    {
        //some code
        this.PreviewKeyDown += ControlB_PreviewKeyDown;
    }
    protected void ControlB_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // do B things
    }
}
```

when the PreviewKeyDown event is fired, both ControlB_ and ControlA_PreviewKeyDown are fired. But I want only ControlB_PreviewKeyDown is fired for a ControlB. Is that possible? If so, how to implement that?

Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you modify the constructor of `ControlA`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your "problem" is due to the fact that ControlB class constructor calls also the ControlA constructor... you can create a ControlA(bool fromParent=true) which doesn't add the handler of this.PreviewKeyDown += ControlA_PreviewKeyDown;

HTH

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you can change the code of both `ControlA` and `ControlB` here's a possible solution:

```
class ControlA
{
    public ControlA(bool subscribe = true)
    {
        if (subscribe)
        {
            this.PreviewKeyDown += ControlA_PreviewKeyDown;
        }
    }
    protected void ControlA_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // do A things
    }
}

class ControlB : ControlA
{
    public ControlB() : base(false)
    {
        //some code
        this.PreviewKeyDown += ControlB_PreviewKeyDown;
    }
    protected void ControlB_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        // do B things
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try setting `e.Handled = true;` in the ControlB handler, and in the ControlA handler, wrap the logic in an `if(!e.Handled)`

Or, since you have the ControlA handler as protected, you can unsubscribe from it in ControlB constructor:

```
    this.PreviewKeyDown += ControlB_PreviewKeyDown;
```

Comment: This is not working since it will call ControlA handler first

Comment: In controlB constructor, try this line: 
        this.PreviewKeyDown -= ControlA_PreviewKeyDown;

Answer (score 0):

In `PreviewKeyDown` we will check for sender type to determine from which control event fired.
Like

```
protected void ControlA_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

    if (sender.GetType() == typeof(ControlA))
    {
        // do A things
    }

}



protected void ControlB_PreviewKeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{

    if (sender.GetType() == typeof(ControlB))
    {
        // do A things
    }

}
```